# How to Get API Paramter?

Tags: magento2, api, parameter

I use a custom API with Delete Method.
I would get this paramter.

```
{
    "id":"1"
}
```

How can i get it in my api response?

etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/news/news/delete" method="DELETE">
        <service class="[Vendor]\[Module]\Api\NewsInterface" method="destroy"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Api/NewsInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace [vendor]\[module]\Api;

/**
* @api
*/

interface NewsInterface
{

    /**
     * Return Added wishlist item.
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return int
     *
     */

    public function destroy($customerId);

}
```

Model/NewsManagement.php

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Model;
use [Vendor]\[Module]\\Api\NewsInterface;

class NewsManagement implements NewsInterface
{
    protected $newsFactory;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request,
        \[Vendor]\[Module]\\Model\NewsFactory $newsFactory
    )
    {
        $this->newsFactory = $newsFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function destroy($customerId) {
        return $customerId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the parameter that will be sent by Magento to the service contract from the webapi.xml: `/:customerId`

Your webapi.xml file will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/news/news/delete/:customerId" method="DELETE">
        <service class="[Vendor]\[Module]\Api\NewsInterface" method="destroy"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

And then you can make a DELETE request to `/V1/news/news/delete/1` to remove the item associated with customerId 1.

Here is how Magento has implemented the DELETE customer:

- [webapi.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/etc/webapi.xml#L228)
- [service contract](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Api/CustomerRepositoryInterface.php#L80)
- [service contract implementation](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository.php#L411)

Comment: yes i know this solutions but what if i would update a item with params?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "update an item with parameters" ?

Comment: its just a put method

Comment: you can apply the same method, but instead of the DELETE method, you need to add PUT.


<route url="/V1/news/news/:customerId" method="PUT">

Answer (score 0):

you have change parameters name `$customerId`  to `$id` at both interface and model class.

```
<?php
namespace [vendor]\[module]\Api;

/**
* @api
*/

interface NewsInterface
{

    /**
     * Return Added wishlist item.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return int
     *
     */

    public function destroy($id);

}
```

and **Model/NewsManagement.php**

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Model;
use [Vendor]\[Module]\\Api\NewsInterface;

class NewsManagement implements NewsInterface
{
    protected $newsFactory;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request,
        \[Vendor]\[Module]\\Model\NewsFactory $newsFactory
    )
    {
        $this->newsFactory = $newsFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
    }
     /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     */
    public function destroy($id) {
        return $id;
    }

}
```

Comment: its said \"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.","parameters":{"fieldName":"id"},"trace":"#0